# With jquery autocomplete widget, how to populate the input value after a selection with my own data

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

In my form text input bar, the json returned by the autocomplete widget will be, [{id = 1,lable="lable1"},......]

```
[{id = 1,label="label1"},{id = 2, label="label2"},......]
```

and I want the input box display value to be "label" which works as default, but I want to the input value to be "id" when I submit the form..

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually keep a <input type='hidden'> right next to the autocomplete input, and then on the select event of the complete I populate that with the ID:

```
 $("#autocomplete-input").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#autocomplete-input-id").val(ui.item.id);
            }

        });
```